# Turn string into a list

Tags: python, python-2.x

I think what I'm trying to turn into a list is a string.

So when I run this it prints out a list of urls. I want to turn those urls into a list like this:

```
["Apple", "Pear", "Radio"]
```

Code:

```
url = "http://www.wired.com/category/science/page/"
a = list(range(1, 12))
i=0


while i < len(a):
    urls1 = url + str(i)
    print urls1[1]
    i+=1
```

What I'm trying to do: (I think that if I combine them both that I can get the urls to go with the scraper.)

```
import urllib
import re


urls = [urls1]
#https://www.wired.com/2016/07/google-tests-new-crypto-chrome-fend-off-quantum-attacks/
i=0

regex = '<h2 class="title brandon clamp-5">(.+?)</h2>'

#https?:(\/\/www\.wired\.com\/2016(\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:\/\?#\[\]@!$&'\(\)\*\+,;\=]*)?)

pattern = re.compile(regex)

while i < len(urls):
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    titles = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)



    for elem in titles: 
        print elem 

    i+=1
```

Comment: So you want a list of urls? Where do the urls come from? What is `urls1`?

Comment: @MoonCheesez Well I originally thought of combining both of them so that is why urls1 is in the bottom one. The urls were originally in a list.

Comment: @MoonCheesez I want to a make a list of urls and then use those urls in the scraper

Answer (score 0):

To get list of 11 urls:

```
url = "http://www.wired.com/category/science/page/"
urls = []
for i in range(1, 12):
    new_url =  url + str(i)
    urls.append(new_url)
print urls
```

Comment: `map("http://www.wired.com/category/science/page/{}".format, range(1, 12))` or `[url + str(i) for i in range(1, 12)]`